# String not storing in a structure properly

Tags: c, string, memory, struct, storage

```
typedef struct class {
   char* CLASS_ID;
   char* CLASS_NAME;
}
```

What would cause those two strings to lose their values over the course of 30-40 unrelated lines of code? (Assigned to a pointer returned from a function called getString()).

Comment: Does the return value of CLASS_ID and CLASS_NAME remains what they should be if you print them out after they have both been initialized using calls to getString()? if they are incorrect after 2nd call then you probably have a problem in getString(). Let me know what you find and we can go from there.

Comment: If you can't work it out by reading your code, your debugger will tell you which code is writing over the memory.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps getString() returns a pointer to a statically allocated buffer, whose value is overwritten each time it is called?

Maybe you're overflowing an array and corrupting your stack or heap?

Maybe you're storing a pointer to a string that was allocated on the stack and has gone out of scope?

With some more information about or code for getString(), someone could probably give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Dang. Beat me with the same answer by less than a minute. Anyway, I have a personal rule that anyone who does that and had the same answer as me is an obvious genius, so +1 for you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, not knowing how `getString()` is implemented, or any of your other code, it could be anything. That is part of the problem with C's (over)use of pointers.

My first guess would be that `getString()` actually returns a pointer to an internal (`static`) string, and thus each call obliterates the value retrieved from the last.

If you are actually using C++, then I would strongly advise you to ditch this code and use std::string instead. I bet your problem magically goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what the other's posted here there's also that you should avoid names like `class`, `CLASS_ID` and `CLASS_NAME` because they are `#defined` in many librarys you might include in the future and debug for hours to find out what's suddenly wrong.